# Align two images side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange the two images in my `HTML` page side by side.

1. I want the images to stay side by side even if the page size changes.
2. I also want the second image to span the entire header of the page ie. all the space left after the first image. The images here are of different size.

For now, I have arranged two images side by side, but when I change the size of the page, the image wraps and comes in the next line after the first image.

Here is my code sample and the CSS:

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<img class="header" src="http://www.placehold.it/160X120" style="float: left;" alt="CCM Logo">
<img class="header" src="http://www.placehold.it/543X120/0000FF" alt="CCM Banner">
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqHMeieegqKI8lpmbD1F?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent wrapping.

```css
.header {
  margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px; /*centering header*/

  height: 120px; position: relative; /*scale header images to 120px*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*keep one-line*/
  overflow: hidden; /*hide excess images parts on small screens*/
}
.header>img { height: 100%;}
```

```html
 

<body>
  <div class="header">
  <img src="http://www.www8-hp.com/in/en/images/T-GE-healthcare-logo__153x115--C-tcm188-1616301--CT-tcm188-1237012-32.jpg" alt="CCM Logo">
  <img src="http://blu-alliance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/healthcare-banner2.jpg" alt="CCM Banner">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `no-wrap` did not help :(

Comment: did not help with what? See you snippet here? Or want you images also change its height for fit window width?

Comment: Your snippet looks fine, but when I insert the code into my fiddle it does not work.

Comment: Is it because you missed html part changes?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  height:120px;
}


HTML:
```

```html
 

<body>
  <img class="header" src="http://www.www8-hp.com/in/en/images/T-GE-healthcare-logo__153x115--C-tcm188-1616301--CT-tcm188-1237012-32.jpg" style="float: left;" alt="CCM Logo">
  <img class="header" src="http://blu-alliance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/healthcare-banner2.jpg" alt="CCM Banner">
</body>
```

Comment: @Akash Curious -> Why are you using `max-width: 50%;`? The images here are of different size and I want the second image to span the entire header of the page ie. all the space left after the first image. Thanks.

Comment: I used max-width: 50%; because I didn't want the resolution of image to go off. If you want the second image to span the entire header, don't give it a fixed height. It will mess around with the resolution.

Comment: But i want the height of both the images to remain the same. I am wanting to do this because I want these two images to be logo and banner of my website header.

Answer (score 0):

Give style

```
.header {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  height: 120px;
}
```

to both images

Comment: Using `float: left;` is a bad practice when it comes to aligning divs or images side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below style:

```
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `max-width` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tcLpnz35/)**

```
.header {
    max-width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
<div class="imgclass">
    <div class="img1">
        your img here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="imgclass">
    <div class="img2">
        your img here
    </div>
</div>
```

On your css file or between `<style>here</style>` this -

```
.imgclass {
    display: table-cell;
}
```